# If $d$ is a metric of a space $X$,under which conditions is $d ^a$ also a metric in $X$?

Tags: real-analysis

The problem is given as follows:

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $A=[a>0:d^a$ is a metric in $X]$.Show that $A$ is a subset of $(0,∞)$.

My attempt thus far:

We will deal first with the case of $a\inℕ$ and use induction.
Assume that $d^n$ is a metric.Then we need to show that $d^{n+1}$ is also a metric.For $n=1$ the statement obviously holds.It is true that:$d^{n+1}(x,y)=d(x,y)d^n(x,y)$ for any $x,y\in X$.

For the three properties of a metric we have:

i)$d^{n+1}(x,x)=d(x,x)d^n(x,x)=0$ since $d(x,x)=d^n(x,x)=0$ and similarly $d^{n+1}(x,y)>0$ for every $x≠y$ in $X$.

ii)As before, $d^{n+1}(x,y)=d^{n+1}(y,x)$ for every $x,y\in X$

iii)We need to show that the triangle inequality holds in the form: $d^{n+1}(x,y)≤d^{n+1}(x,z)+d^{n+1}(z,y)$ for every $x,y,z\in X$.To simplify notation,let $d(x,y)=α, d(x,z)=β$ and $d(z,y)=γ$. So,for the triangle equality to be satisfied it has to be true that: $α^{n+1}≤β^{n+1}+γ^{n+1}$ But it is easy to find a counterexample of that.For $n=2,α=1,β=1/2,γ=1/2$ it is not true since it amounts to: $1≤1/8+1/8=1/4$.So the triangle inequality does not hold and thus $a∉ℕ$ for $a≠1$.

But I have found no other way to describe $A$,or show that it is a subspace of $(0,∞)$ as desired by the exercise.Any hints/answers will be more than welcome!

Comment: How is $d^a$ defined?

Comment: The exercise was given with no further clarification but myself and other students safely(?) assumed that it means the a-th power of $d$.

Comment: What do you mean by "subspace of $(0,\infty)$"?

Comment: Sorry! Subset-Will edit immediately! Spent all day studying Groups so..

Comment: The restriction $a > 0$ already implies that $A \subset (0, +\infty)$, even if $A$ is empty.

Comment: Your reasoning is faulty: the discrete metric $d$ on $X$ certainly satisfies $d^a=d$ for every $a>0$. The discrete metric is defined by $d(x,x)=0$, $d(x,y)=1$ if $x\ne y$.

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample ! So,where did I err?

Comment: "Show that A is a subset of (0,∞)." As said by others, A is **defined** as being a subset of (0,∞). So, what is there to prove?

Comment: @Did I don't know..The problem was given exactly as such..Perhaps our professor made a mistake..

Comment: The title, on the other hand, makes sense (especially when one knows the answer, I must admit).

Comment: @Did If he meant that it is a metric for every $a>0$? Does that make sense? If so,I will edit it.

Comment: It is not, not for every $d$ and every $a>0$.

Comment: Sorry to be obtuse, but, this is exactly how the problem was given to you? By the way, title or body?

Comment: You are not being obtuse at all-I am very perplexed and even sad with the outcome.I don't want to leave a flawed question open..Yes,this is exactly as it was given-copied from the blackboard.Oh,the body is as given..the title is mine..

Comment: Maybe the professor meant to ask to show that it is a subinterval? (And in fact, if $d^a$ is a metric, then $d^b$ is a metric for every $b \in (0,a)$.)

Comment: @LukasGeyer Yes mr.Geyer!..During class today he clarified that is what he wanted and gave a proof of precisely what you suggested.I suppose I will edit the post with that proof or answer it myself.